# How create mysql query that will show only before and after of one specific record?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query that is order by alphabetical order

```
select id, color_name from colors order by color_name
```

output

```
| 4 | blue
| 1 | red
| 2 | violet
| 3 | yellow
```

i want to query the before and after record of specific record. example:  red

desired output:

```
| 4 | blue
| 1 | red
| 2 | violet
```

thanks.

Comment: maybe not the best way but you could select the table into a temp table/table variable ordered by color_name and add an identity column. Then you could select from that temp table where color = red OR where identitycolumn between red's identity +/- 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a UNION:

```
SELECT  A.id, A.color_name FROM  (
   (
      SELECT  id, color_name FROM colors
      WHERE color_name <= 'red'
      ORDER BY color_name DESC
      LIMIT 2
   )
  UNION
   (
      SELECT id, color_name FROM colors
      WHERE color_name > 'red'
      ORDER BY color_name ASC
      LIMIT 1
   )

 ) as A
ORDER BY A.color_name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable to rank result sets, then join the same result set onto itself where the color name is red and the rank number is within 1 position of the rank of 'red':

```
SELECT b.id, b.color_name
FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn 
    FROM colors a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) AS var_init
    ORDER BY a.color_name
) a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.*, @rn2:=@rn2+1 AS rn 
    FROM colors a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn2:=0) AS var_init
    ORDER BY a.color_name
) b ON a.color_name = 'red' AND a.rn IN (b.rn-1, b.rn, b.rn+1)
```

If you happen to be searching for a color that's at the beginning or end of the list, then of course, only two results will show.

---

### Check the demo out on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81c90/20/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, color_name from (
          select rowno, id, color_name from (
              select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rowno, id, color_name from 
                  colors, (select @rownum:=0) t1 
              order  by color_name
          ) t2
where rowno in (@row:=( 
          select rowno from (
              select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rowno, color_name 
              from colors, (
                        select @rownum:=0) t3 
              order  by color_name
              ) t4 
          where color_name = "red"), @row + 1, @row -1 )) t5
```